# How to access ForeignKey properties from models.py in django

Tags: python, django, model, foreign-keys

I want to access a property of another model from a model via ForeignKey. For example, if `invoice_details` is a ForeignKey to `InvoiceMaster`, then I want `invoice_details` to store the value of `InvoiceMaster`'s `invoice_number`, instead of the primary key. How can I achieve this?

I have tried the following:

```
class OrderDetails(models.Model):
    purchase_order_number = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    purchase_request_number = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    delivery_no = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    delivery_equipment = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    delivery_quantity = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    warranty_start_date = models.DateField()
    warranty_end_date = models.DateField()
    invoice_details = models.ForeignKey(InvoiceMaster, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True).invoice_number
    vendor_id = models.ForeignKey(VendorDetails, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True).vendor_id
    equipment_id = models.ForeignKey(EquipmentMaster, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True).equipment_id
    is_visible = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Check `invoice_details` - I've tried adding `.invoice_number` at the end of the ForeignKey. Adding `.invoice_details` to `InvoiceMaster` within the ForeignKey parentheses gave me the following error: `TypeError: ForeignKey(<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x10d632fd0>) is invalid. First parameter to ForeignKey must be either a model, a model name, or the string 'self'`

Here is the `InvoiceMaster` module:

```
class InvoiceMaster(models.Model):
    invoice_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    equipment_name = models.ForeignKey(EquipmentMaster, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True).name
    quantity = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_visible = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

For some reason, although I have done the same thing in `equipment_name` over here as I had in `invoice_details`, Django shows no error. For extra context, please take a look at `EquipmentMaster`, which `equipment_name` has a link to via ForeignKey.

```
class EquipmentMaster(models.Model):
    equipment_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    equipment_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=equipment_categories)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    ram = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    storage = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    display_size = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    paper_size = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    operating_system = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    is_visible = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get details of the `InvoiceMaster` in `OrderDetails` by doing the following in `OrderDetails`:

```
@property
def invoice_number(self):
    return self.invoice_details.invoice_number
```

with this, you can get the `invoice_number` from order_details by calling `order_details.invoice_number`.

You might want to check if there is a relation before accessing the foreignkey field.

Answer (score 1):

May I ask what's the purpose behind this?

A `ForeignKey` is only a relation to another field. If it is only because of displaying the `invoice_number` instead of the pk try adding the following:

```
class InvoiceMaster(models.Model):
    invoice_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    # your other fields

    def __str__(self).
        return self.invoice_number
```

Otherwise you can only fetch invoice_number directly from the ForeignKey like

```
order = OrderDetails.objects.get(pk=1)
invoice_number = order.invoice_details.invoice_number
```

Comment: Does this work if `invoice_number` is not just a number, but can include alphanumeric characters?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter as you've declared the field as CharField which is always interpreted as string. If you want to change it to an IntegerField you have to convert it before return inside `__str__` like with `return str(self.invoice_nuber)` or `return f"{self.invoice_number}"`